# JavaFX ListView Display Single Column from 2 Column Observable List

Tags: listview, javafx, observable

I got some great advice from @Fabian but I can't get see any data in my ListView :

```
public class MenuController implements Initializable {
@FXML
ListView menuList1;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    ObservableList<EmployeeDivision> divisionListRow = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        Connection conn;
        conn = Connect_db.getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT ID,Division FROM tbl_ref_employee_divisions";
        PreparedStatement prestate = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet divsResult = prestate.executeQuery();
        while (divsResult.next()) {
            divisionListRow.add(new EmployeeDivision(divsResult.getInt(1), divsResult.getString(2)));
        menuList1.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<EmployeeDivision>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(EmployeeDivision item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(empty || item == null ? "" : item.getName());
            }
        });
    }
        prestate.close();
        divsResult.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have no idea how the lambda works..but I'll get there..
Debugging I can see that `divisionListRow` is getting populated. But I'm expecting data `divsResult.getString(2)` to appear.
tks

Comment: Declare `menuList1` as `ListView<EmployeeDivision>` (assuming you've created an `EmployeeDivision` class with getters/setters; if not, you need to create one). You also need to `menuList1.setItems(divisionListRow)` to associate the data with the `ListView`. Lastly, the `setCellFactory` should not be done in the data load loop. It only needs to be declared once. I'm still a relative Java newbie but also come from a VB/Access background.  This tutorial [Database Operations in JavaFX](https://www.swtestacademy.com/database-operations-javafx/) helped me a lot. I shall post some code in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things that I can see ...

Declare your `ListView` as `ListView<EmployeeDivision>`.  That sets its type to `EmployeeDivision`.

The `setCellFactory` should not be in the `while (divsResult.next())` data load loop.  It only needs to be declared once, not every time a row is loaded from the DB into the `ObservableList`.

You need to do a `menuList1.setItems(divisionListRow)`.  `setItems()` is the thing that associates your data with the `ListView`.

Here's a MVCE that produces a `ListView` that looks like this:

[image]

When you click on a state, it will output the division ID to the console.

The MVCE uses the SQLite database.  The table and data for the MVCE can be created with this SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee_Divisions (
    ID       INTEGER,
    Division VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO Employee_Divisions
VALUES
(1, 'Queensland'),
(2, 'New South Wales'),
(3, 'Victoria'),
(4, 'South Australia'),
(5, 'Northern Territory'),
(6, 'Western Australia'),
(7, 'Tasmania');
```

Here's the code.

```
package test42;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig;

public class Test42 extends Application {

    private static final String dbName = "TestDB.db";
    private static final String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlite:" + dbName;
    private static final String dbDriver = "org.sqlite.JDBC";


    private Parent createContent() {

        //*************************************************************************************
        //Declare an ObservableList for the ListView
        ObservableList<EmployeeDivisions> olEmployeeDivisions = FXCollections.observableArrayList(empdiv -> new Observable[] {});

        //*************************************************************************************
        //Get the data from the DB and add it to the ObservableList.
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Employee_Divisions;";
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> resultSet = doDatabaseSelect(sql);

        olEmployeeDivisions.clear();

        for ( ArrayList<Object> resultRow : resultSet ) {
            EmployeeDivisions newEmployeeDivision = new EmployeeDivisions();
            newEmployeeDivision.addList(resultRow);
            olEmployeeDivisions.add(newEmployeeDivision);
        }

        //*************************************************************************************
        //Declare the ListView
        ListView<EmployeeDivisions> lvEmployeeDivisions = new ListView<>();

        //Set its data to the ObservableList
        lvEmployeeDivisions.setItems(olEmployeeDivisions);

        //Set its cell factory to only show the division name
        lvEmployeeDivisions.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<EmployeeDivisions>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(EmployeeDivisions item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(empty || item == null ? "" : item.getDivisionName());
            }
        });

        //Ouput the division ID when a division name is clicked
        lvEmployeeDivisions.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
            EmployeeDivisions selectedItem = lvEmployeeDivisions.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (selectedItem != null) {
                System.out.println("Division ID = " + selectedItem.getDivisionId());
            }
        });

        //*************************************************************************************
        //Create a BorderPane and add the ListView
        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(lvEmployeeDivisions);

        return content;

    }

    //*************************************************************************************
    //Data model

    private class EmployeeDivisions {

        private IntegerProperty divisionId;
        private StringProperty divisionName;

        private EmployeeDivisions() {
            this(0, "");
        }

        private EmployeeDivisions(
            int divisionId,
            String divisionName
        ) {
            this.divisionId = new SimpleIntegerProperty(divisionId);
            this.divisionName = new SimpleStringProperty(divisionName);
        }

        private int getDivisionId() {
            return divisionId.get();
        }

        private void setDivisionId(int divisionId) {
            this.divisionId.set(divisionId);
        }

        private IntegerProperty divisionIdProperty() {
            return divisionId;
        }

        private String getDivisionName() {
            return divisionName.get();
        }

        private void setDivisionName(String divisionName) {
            this.divisionName.set(divisionName);
        }

        private StringProperty divisionNameProperty() {
            return divisionName;
        }

        private void addList(ArrayList<Object> list) {

            this.divisionId.set((int) list.get(0));
            this.divisionName.set((String) list.get(1));

        }

    }

    //*************************************************************************************
    //Methods to connect to and query the database and execute DML

    public Connection connectToDB()  {

        Connection cnx = null;
        File dbPath = new File(dbName);

        if ( dbPath.exists()){

            try {
                Class.forName(dbDriver);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException exception) {
                System.err.println("Database driver class not found");
            }

            try {

                SQLiteConfig config = new SQLiteConfig();
                config.enforceForeignKeys(true);
                cnx = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,config.toProperties());
                cnx.setAutoCommit(true);

            } catch (SQLException exception) {
                System.err.println("Error connecting to database " + dbName);
            }     

        } else {
            System.err.println("Database " + dbName + " not found!");
        }
        return cnx;

    }

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> doDatabaseSelect(String sql) {

        int colNum = 0;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> resultSet = new ArrayList<>();

        Connection cnx = connectToDB();
        if ( cnx == null ) return null;

        try (
                Statement stmt = cnx.createStatement();
        ) {
            try (
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)
                ) {
                    ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();
                    //Add each DB row as an Object to the dbRow ArrayList ...
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        ArrayList<Object> dbRow = new ArrayList<>();
                        for ( int i=0; i<rsMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++ ) {
                            colNum = i + 1;
                            switch ( rsMetaData.getColumnTypeName(colNum).trim() ) {
                                case "VARCHAR" :
                                    String stringCol = rs.getString(colNum);
                                    dbRow.add(stringCol);
                                    break;
                                case "INTEGER" :
                                    int intCol = rs.getInt(colNum);
                                    dbRow.add(intCol);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        //... then add the dbRow to the final resultSet.
                        resultSet.add(dbRow);
                    }
                //Having added all the DB rows, return the resultSet.
                return resultSet;
            }

        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            System.err.println(exception);
            return null;
        }

    }

    private void doDatabaseDML(String sql) {

        Connection cnx = connectToDB();
        if ( cnx == null ) return;

        try (
            Statement stmt = cnx.createStatement();
        ) {

            cnx.setAutoCommit(true);
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            System.err.println(exception);
            return;
        }     

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: many thanks for all of your effort @GreenZebra. I cannot run your code in a new package, I get too many errors - bad enough with one problem! :-)..in any event that may be my fault. But the 3 suiggestions you provided has solved my problem I can now see a list..I guess you know the feeling of relief that brings!. many thanks

Comment: No problems, happy to help. And yes, I know that feeling of relief very well!  I forgot to mention I'm running SQLite.  The JDBC connect string, DB driver and DB connection method in my code could be causing problems if you're running off Access.  Not to worry, you got your program working in the end.